# Angularjs Make a basket for products

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a new angularjs learner. I work on my project.

```
        <div ng-controller="urunKontrolcusu">
<img id="spinner" ng-src="spinner.gif" style="visibility:hidden;width:40px;">       

                <div class="row youplay-side-news" ng-repeat="x in products">
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-4">
                  <a href="#" class="angled-img">
                    <div class="img">

                      <img height="60" src="{{x.ResimLink}}" alt="{{x.UrunAdi}}"> 
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-8">
                  <a ng-click="deleteProduct(x.id)" style="text-decoration: none; top:20px;" class="pull-right mr-10"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>

                  <h4 class="ellipsis"><a href="#">{{x.ProductName}}</a></h4>
                  <span class="quantity">{{x.quantity}} × <span class="amount">{{x.UnitAmount}} $</span></span>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="ml-20 mr-20 pull-right"><strong>Total:</strong>  <span class="amount"> {{quantity*UnitAmount}}    $</span>
              </div>
              <div class="btn-group pull-right m-15">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Sepeti İncele</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Ödeme Yap</a>
              </div> 
          </div>
```

I don't know how I can show total amount ?
I would like to make a basket. It list things which have bought by customer. I want to show total amount all of the products whick have listed on basket.
please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<div>Total: {{ getTotal() }}</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$scope.getTotal = function(){
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.products.length; i++){
        var product = $scope.products[i];
        total += (product.price * product.quantity);
    }
    return total;
}
```

---

Alternative Solution:

In your ng-repeat add this:

```
ng-init="itemTotal = product.price * product.quantity; total = total + itemTotal"
```

Then in your controller store the scope variable `$scope.total` and call it at the end with `<div>Total Price: {{ total }}</div>`